# What are the advantages/disadvantages of wxPython's AGW AUI?

Tags: python, wxpython

We are currently using the **[wx.aui](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxAUI)** module in our program. I've been told that we could use the module **[wx.lib.agw.aui](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/AGW_Docs/index.html)** which is a pure python version.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using the agw.aui module instead of the standard aui provided by wxPython?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to what cfedermann mentioned, the AGW implementation is updated frequently. The author accepts patches and new feature requests. It's just more active period. Plus because it's pure Python, the developers that use it can hack it a lot easier to suit their own specific needs then they could with the C++ version.

Answer (score 3):

`wx.lib.agw.aui` is a re-implementation of `wx.aui` using only Python code.

It was created *"because wx.aui has a decade-old bug related to toolbars opened
on wxTrac which has never been fixed."* (Source: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.wxpython/83540)

The disadvantage may be the reduced speed as a pure Python implementation may be slower than C/C++ code.